# How to call specific some function right after calling __init__ in Python?

Tags: python, init, metaclass

Here is an example class `Permit`:

```
class Permit(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Permit, self).__init__()
        # init todo list
        self.todo = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

What I wanna do:

- register some new elements in `self.todo` list, but not affect the original `__init__` function
- `self.todo` must be modified right after `__init__` is called (just like a new `__init__` function)
- for example, I want to insert new element into `self.todo` just like the following, but the element and insert location is uncertain and specified by users

```
class Permit(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Permit, self).__init__()
        # init todo list
        self.todo = [1,2,3,4,5]
        
        # new elements
        self.todo.insert(6,3)
```

I know adding function parameters in `__init__` may help, like `def __init__(self, elements, locations):`. However, this modification is `instance`-level, when there are many instances created by `Permit` class, you have to modified them one by one.

So I want to register new elements in `class`-level, which means the new elements can be registered after calling `__init__` function (just like modifying the original `__init__`).

I wonder if I can register new elements in some certain function and make sure they are called right after calling `__init__` function.

PS: Does `metaclass` help and how?

############################################################
Update: sorry for my poor language, I will describe my requirement more specific in the following:
I have:

- a default class (Permit)

```
class Permit(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Permit, self).__init__()
        # init todo list
        self.todo = [1,2,3,4,5]
        ... # deal with todo list
```

- a default config file

```
from yacs.config import CfgNode as CN
cfg = CN()
...
```

what I wanna do:

- support user to add plugin methods, consisted by **extra** config file and method file like:
  extra config file:

```
def add_cfg(cfg):
    cfg.method = CN()
    cfg.method.param1 = 1.
```

extra function file and a registery

```
new_element1=1
new_element2=2
registry = {"new_element1": {"class": Permit, "position":-1,}, "new_element2": {"class": Permit, "position":4,}}
```

- I don't want the users to modify source code, adding new configs and method file as plugin is enough.
- `Permit` is already called in the my library, so I wish not to create a new child class like `Permit2`

Comment: You could inherit from that class and change the `__init__` call? For example: `class Permit2(Permit):`. You could leave the other methods as-is if need be.

Comment: Is a second "constructor" that accepts parameters what you want?

Comment: @jhso , thanks, it is feasible. but the modification is user-specific, which means it's uncertain (just like plugin functions specified by user). I wonder if I can modify it in the original ```Permit``` class.

Comment: @lain Shelvington Yes, just what I want to do. and the "constructor" is class-level, just like adding new code in the end of the original ```__init__``` function in source code.

Comment: I'm confused about what sort of class-level modifications you think you can make here. Do you want to be able to change the default value of `todo`, so that new instances made after you specify the change will start differently? That's doable with class variables. But I'm not very confident that's actually what you want. Can you give an example of how a user of this class could specify things and create some instances so we can understand which instances get changed when?

Comment: @Blckknght, sorry for weak language, more description is added

Comment: So the new code is appreciated, but none of it connects together. How does `add_cfg` interact with `Permit` instances? What does the last code block mean, at all? I see there's something in the middle called `Permit`, but is that an instance of the `Permit` class, or something else? Is that the text of a config file? I'm so confused, which doesn't bode well for being able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can add additional "constructors" in Python by using class methods that instantiate an instance of the class and perform modifications to that instance

```
class Permit(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Permit, self).__init__()
        # init todo list
        self.todo = [1,2,3,4,5]

    @classmethod
    def with_mod(cls, position, value):
        obj = cls()
        obj.todo.insert(position, value)
        return obj


foo = Permit()  # Instance with the default todo list
bar = Permit.with_mod(6, 3) # Instance where the todo list is then modified
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a good idea. But still I wonder if I can do it without changing the way of calling (```Permit(xx) ```), more description is added for the problem.

Comment: @david from your update seems like you're asking how to monkey patch a class from an external module specifically the `__init__` method based on some config?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I quite understood what you need - but for one thing metaclasses can help, if you can attach a custom metaclass to your `Permit` class:

The metaclass ' `__call__` method is what is responsible for creating a new instance of a class: it will call `__new__` on the class, which returns a new, unitialized instance, then call `__init__` passing it the instance `__new__` returned, and return that instance again (disregaring the return value of `__init__`).

If you want something to run after `__init__`, just add this logic to a custom metaclass **call**`:

```
class PostInit(type):  # deriving from type is what makes a metaclass
   def __call__(cls, *args, **kw):
       instance = super().__call__(*args, **kw) # "instance" now contains the new instance, after __init__ is run
       
       # code to retrieve custom configurations and apply to the instance:
       ...
       return instance


class Permit(metaclass=PostInit):
    ...
```